# Android java.lang.NullPointerException not able to populate the listview

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, listview

I'm trying to populate a listview with some data from json.

Here are the errors I am getting:

```
04-17 12:54:25.573: E/JSON Parser(1169): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:
of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169): Process: com.example.mysqltest, PID: 1169
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169): at com.example.mysqltest.PropertyView$JSONParseP.onPostExecute(PropertyView.java:95)
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at com.example.mysqltest.PropertyView$JSONParseP.onPostExecute(PropertyView.java:1)
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-17 12:54:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my Java file...

```
  JSONArray array = null


      public void onClick(View view) 
             new JSONParseP().execute()

    private class JSONParseP extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>

        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args)
        JSONParserP jParser = new JSONParserP();
        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrlP(url);
        return json;

         protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) 
         pDialog.dismiss();
         try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
             array = json.getJSONArray(null);
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(i);
```

Any help I would highly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Which line is line 95 of `PropertyView`

Comment: `array = json.getJSONArray(null);` What is the name of the JSONArray that you are looking for?

Comment: Please show us full code of `onPostExecute`-method including your try-catch-block and the line causing NPE, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(i);` to `JSONArray c = array.getJSONArray(i);`

Comment: I cannot see how this might help. For example: Maybe variable `array` is `null`. OP has not yet shown enough information (line of NPE).

Comment: what method should i use to get the string?

Comment: 04-17 12:54:25.573: E/JSON Parser(1169): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:
of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

  this means that he tries to read a json array into a json object, since he didn't point out which line it is, i was trying to guess